# Test if two numpy arrays are (close to) equal, including shape

Tags: python, numpy

I want to test if two numpy arrays are (close to) equal, so I've been using the `np.allclose` function. The only problem is, it returns `True` if given a two-dimensional matrix and a three-dimensional matrix of equal elements.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[3.14159265, -0.1], [-0.1, 0.1]])

y = np.array([[math.pi, -0.1], [-0.1, 0.1]])

z1 = np.array([[[3.14159265, -0.1], [-0.1, 0.1]],
              [[3.14159265, -0.1], [-0.1, 0.1]]])
z2 = np.array([[[math.pi, -0.1], [-0.1, 0.1]],
              [[math.pi, -0.1], [-0.1, 0.1]]])  


np.allclose(x,y)
# Returns true, as expected

np.allclose(x,z1)
# Also returns true, even though matrices are different shapes. Unwanted.
```

Now, I know about `np.array_equal`, which compares elements and shape, but it doesn't allow me to test if the elements are close, only if they are equal. For instance,

```
np.array_equal(x,y)
```

Returns `False`

Is there a function I can use that will return true for `(x,y)` and `(z1,z2)` but false for `(x,z1)` in this case?

Comment: How about adding one more check there - `(x.shape == z1.shape) & np.allclose(x,z1)`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What's happening is that `allclose` broadcasts its input.  This allows comparisons with similarly shaped arrays (e.g. `3` and `[3, 3, 3]`) following the [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

---

For your purposes, have a look at the `numpy.testing` functions, specifically [`np.testing.assert_allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_allclose.html#numpy.testing.assert_allclose) or [`assert_array_almost_equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal.html), which will check for shape as well as values.  (I don't remember the difference between those two offhand, but it relates to the way they calculate floating point differences.)

These are particularly handy if you're using assert-based unit testing.

Most (all?) of the `numpy.testing.assert_*` functions check for array shape as well as value equality.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.testing.assert_allclose([1], [[1]])
```

Which yields:

```
AssertionError:
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0

(shapes (1,), (1, 1) mismatch)
 x: array([1])
 y: array([[1]])
```

Another useful (and currently not as well documented as it could be) thing to know about these functions is that they compare `NaN`'s as equal.

For example, this will succeed:

```
In [3]: np.testing.assert_allclose([np.nan], [np.nan])
```

While `numpy.allclose` will return `False` for the same case:

```
In [4]: np.allclose([np.nan], [np.nan])
Out[4]: False
```

On a side note, `numpy.isclose` (but not `allclose`) has an `equal_nan` kwarg to control this.

Comment: I am doing assert-based unit testing, so this works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Note that `np.testing.assert_allclose(1, [1, 1])` and similar still pass: a single float (numpy scalar, `np.array(1)`) is still broadcasted. Perhaps because these don't have a `shape` attribute (or one that the empty tuple).

Comment: A video explaining `np.testing.assert_allclose` and others: 
https://youtu.be/sai1g5fjyb8